# How to create a third level picklist based on first two piclist values, and limit items based on selections

Tags: picklist, dependent-picklist

I want to create a picklist which and populate items in it based on the first two picklist.

The first picklist 'A' is a standard 'Type' having items aa ab ac ad
The second picklist 'B' is a custom dependent picklist on 'A' eg: aa -> aax,aay, ab->abx,aby , ac->acx, acy..

Till here I am able to create.

Now I have to create on more picklist field, whose values should be dependent on the combination values

ie., Lets assume C has items ca cb cc cd

Now I have to populat picklist items as below:

if A is aa, B is acx then C ->ca, cb
if A is aa, B is acy then C ->ca, cd

For A and B i was able to do it through dependency matrix. Looking for help in imlpementing logic for 'C'.

Comment: So your dependency in `C` is only on `B` because `A` does not need to participate. Just do a simple field dependency of `C` on `B` and specify values as your example -> if `B` is `acx` then `ca, cb`, `acy` then `ca, cd`.

Comment: How are you attempting to do this? Standard configuration, Visualforce, Aura, Web Components, etc? We'll need more detail in order to assist you.

Comment: @zaitsman my C values is dependent on both B and A. I am able to create dependencies between A and B. Now I have to make C populate values based on selected items in both A and B.

Comment: Not in the example you gave they are not.

Comment: @sfdcfox Right now I am trying in standard configuration. How to achieve in standard config? or is there any other ways where I can implement easily.